# Quiz with paginated questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Right now I have one-page quiz with all questions one under another.
What I want to do is let user cycle next/previous each question without changing site (ergo url doesn't change) and after cycling through all questions, let user submit the form and see the results.
paginate gem is not quite it.

Is there a way to do that in rails only?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, search for endless scrolling in rails and you will have endless examples. I am not going to write the entire code for you but to get you started:

```
 Controller

 @quiz = Quiz.find_by(params[:id])
 @questions = @quiz.questions.order('created_at desc').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
   respond_to do |format|
    format.js
   end
 end

view

@questions.each do |question|
  question.content
end

will_paginate @questions

<div id="more_questions_btn" style="display: none"> 
  More
</div>

jquery 

if ($('#more_questions).size > 0) {
  $('.pagination').hide() 
  $('#more_questions_btn).show() 
}
var url= $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
('#more_questions_btn').on('click', function() {
 $.getscript(url)
}
```

and then you need to use the js.erb file to append the next page of questions or replace the current set of questions.